# How to count ocurrences of substings in string from text file - python

Tags: python, string, substring, contains, text-segmentation

I want to **count the number of lines on a .txt file were a string contains two sub-strings**.

I tried the following:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        wordsList = line.split()
        if any("leads" and "show" in s for s in wordsList):
            repetitions +=1

print "Repetitions: %i"  % (repetitions)
```

But it doesn't seem to be working as it should.
With the following demo input file I got **3 repetitions** when it should be 2:

```
www.google.es/leads/hello/show
www.google.es/world
www.google.com/leads/nyc/oops
www.google.es/leads/la/show
www.google.es/leads/nope/pop
leads.
show
```

I also tried chaning "any" for "all" but I get even stranger results.

Comment: You mean `"leads" in s and "show" in s`

Comment: @ThierryLathuille oh god it worked Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"leads" and "show" in s` is interpreted as:
`"leads" and ("show" in s)` because of precedence.

Python tries to interpret "leads" as a boolean. As it is a non-empty string, it evaluates to True.

So, your expression is equivalent to `"show" in s`

What you mean is:
`"leads" in s and "show" in s`